# CMake cyclic dependency error when a custom library name is the same as a system library

Tags: c++, cmake, shared-libraries, cyclic-dependency

I'm writing a CMakeLists.txt file to build a C++ project of mine, which is composed of

1. libhybris.so: A shared library with some exported functions.
2. hybris: An executable which links to libhybris.so
3. A set of various shared libraries which links to libhybris.so

The problem is that, libhybris.so depends on libpcre (for regular expression capabilities), so I have the following statements:

```
# libhybris.so generation
add_library( libhybris 
             SHARED 
             ${LIB_SOURCES} )

...

# Needed libraries
target_link_libraries( libhybris 
                       dl 
                       pcre 
                       pthread
                       readline )
```

And one of the shared libraries from point 3, is called pcre.so, so I have the following too:

```
add_library( pcre SHARED ${PCRE_SOURCES} )

...

target_link_libraries( pcre
                       dl 
                       pcre 
                       curl
                       pthread
                       readline
                       ffi 
                       libhybris )
```

So, when I run a "cmake .", I have the following error:

```
-- Configuring done
CMake Error: The inter-target dependency graph contains the following strongly connected component (cycle):
  "libhybris" of type SHARED_LIBRARY
    depends on "pcre"
  "pcre" of type SHARED_LIBRARY
    depends on "libhybris"
At least one of these targets is not a STATIC_LIBRARY.  Cyclic dependencies are allowed only among static libraries.
```

Because CMake thinks that the libhybris.so pcre dependency (system libpcre.so) is the same of my pcre.so which it is obviously not.

How can I solve this problem **without** changing the pcre.so name?

Answer (score 2):

In CMake, the recommended way is to specify any link libraries with the full path. To get the full path for the system library, you can either use `FIND_PACKAGE(...)` if supported or simply `FIND_LIBRARY(...)`

For example,

```
FIND_LIBRARY( PCRE_SYSTEM_LIB pcre )

ADD_LIBRARY( libhybris SHARED ${LIB_SOURCES} )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( libhybris
                       ${PCRE_SYSTEM_LIB}
                       ......
                      )
```

This will prevent CMake from expanding something it recognizes as a target (nameley `pcre`) to the full path of that target.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your development environments. You can set a build path to overcome these difficulties.

Comment: If i don't set the name explicitly (giving the full path of libhybris.so for instance) cmake will not recognize libhybris.so as a dependency of pcre.so, i've already tried that.